# Hide label in button click in MVC5 JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of label controls. On edit click I want to hide label and show the text box. My labels got ID on runtime.

Here is my view --

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Edit').click(function () {
      hide label and show text control
    });

  });

</script>


<table>
  @for (var i = 0; i < Model.LogData.Count; i++)
  {
    <tr>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.LogData[i].BeginMiles)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.LogData[i].EndMiles)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LogData[i].EndMiles, new { @class   = "edit-input" })
      </td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>

<div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
  <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="exit" value="Exit">
  <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="Edit" value="Edit" id="Edit"  >
```

Please help me to perform this function.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used php to generate 'div's and a jQuery script for the function.Which has been organized for re-use.I think it may help

```
<div class="main">
<?php for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) {
  $html = "<div class='sections'><label class='labels'>label - $i </label></ br>";
  $html .= "<input type='text' class='textbox'></br>";
  $html .= "<button class='edit'>edit</button></br></div>";
  echo $html;
}
 ?>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 (function($, window, document, undefined){
  var
    constants = {
      main : '.main',
      sections : '.sections',
      textbox : '.textbox',
      edit : '.edit',
      labels : '.labels'
    },
    properties = {
      mainDiv : null,
      sectionDiv : null,
      edit : null,
      textbox : null,
      labels : null,
    },
    methods = {

      init: function() {
          properties.mainDiv = $(constants.main);
          properties.sectionDiv = properties.mainDiv.find($(constants.sections));
          properties.edit = properties.sectionDiv.find($(constants.edit));
          properties.textbox = properties.sectionDiv.find($(constants.textbox));
          properties.labels = properties.sectionDiv.find($(constants.labels));
          properties.textbox.css({
                   display: 'none'
                 });
          properties.edit.click(methods.run);

    },
    run : function (event){
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.parent().find(properties.labels).toggle();
      $this.parent().find(properties.textbox).toggle();
    }
  };
 $(document).ready(methods.init);
 })(jQuery, window, document);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("label").css("display", "none");
$("textarea").css("display", "block");
```

or

```
$("label").hide();
$("textarea").show();
```

The first solution assumes that in your initial styling you have set `label` to not display (i.e:

```
label {
    display: block;
}
```

...and `textarea` to the opposite of that (`none`)

In future, I recommend googling a question before you ask it one here as it's a relatively simple question and would take no more than 5 mins top find the answer yourself.
Just a tip for the future.

Also worth mentioning, this code will apply to all `label`'s and `textarea`'s in your HTML. To single out individual elements or a set of them, apply and `id` or a `class` to the element(s) (i.e:

```
<label id="yourid"></label>
<textarea class="yourclass"></textarea>
```

`id`'s are unique to an element so no 2 elements can have the same `id`'s
`class`'s can be shared among elements, it's a way to group elements together

And I'm assuming when you said 'textbox' you actually meant `textarea`

To try and get the `label` you're talking of, do:

```
$("label[for='edit-input']").css("display", "none");
```

...which will hopefully select the specific one

Comment: This answer will work but I think its important to note that all labels throughtout will be set to display: none;

Comment: @Enjayy I understand. It was hard to come up with a solution as OP didn't provide any HTML to work with. I will mention it though

Comment: I don't want to hide all the labels. I just want to hide label m.LogData[i].EndMiles.

Comment: I think putting `[for="edit-input"]` may do the trick as it looks

Comment: No, it's not working... in my page DisplayFor is in TD and number of DisplayFor will depend on "Model.LogData.Count". and I want to hide all the DisplayFor "m.LogData[i].EndMiles" not others.

Answer (score 0):

i made an easy example.

html:

```
<label id="Label">hi</label>
<br/>
<input id="Text" type="text" class="hidden" />
<br/>
<button id="Edit">edit</button>
```

css:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

javasctipt:

```
$('#Edit').click(function() {
  $('#Label').hide();
  $('#Text').val('hi').show();
});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L3L494ys/)

I hope this code helps you.

Answer (score 0):

@wmash's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37998422/3282354) is pretty much what you want to do, you just need to add an Id to the label that MVC generates. Also, you need to have some way to identify which row you want to toggle when you click the button.

Here is the code you used to generate the HTML modified to add an ID:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.LogData[i].EndMiles, new { @Id = "lblEndMiles" + i })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LogData[i].EndMiles, new { 
    @Id = "txtEndMiles" + i, 
    @class = "edit-input" 
})
```

Note that `lblEndMiles` and `txtEndMiles` can be changed to something else if you prefer.

Next you need to change the edit button. There are two ways to do this, one is to have an edit button be on each row that toggles that row. The other is to have a "selected" row that the edit button affects. Here is what the click handler should look like if you go the selected row route.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#Edit').click(function () {
    // get the selected row
    var selectedId = getSelectedRow();
    var lblId = "#lblEndMiles" + selectedId;
    var txtId = "#txtEndMiles" + selectedId;

    //hide and show the controls as in @wmash's answer
    $(lblId).hide();
    $(txtId).show();
  });
});
```

A quick way to make the row selection work is to add a click event to each row that removes a "selected" class from every other row and adds it to the clicked row.

---

If you want to toggle all the labels and text boxes at once, you can instead add a class to each label and text box and use the classname and jquery to toggle it.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.LogData[i].EndMiles, new { @class = "lblEndMiles" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LogData[i].EndMiles, new { @class = "txtEndMiles edit-input" 
})
```

Again, note that I choose `lblEndMiles` and `txtEndMiles` as example class names and you are free to change them.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#Edit').click(function () {

    //hide and show the controls as in @wmash's answer
    $(".lblEndMiles").hide();
    $(".txtEndMiles").show();
  });
});
```